# Transmit location data globally

Tags: gps, gsm

While looking at products like:
https://www.victorinox.com/global/en/Products/Travel-Gear/Accessories/CheckSmart-Luggage-Tracker/p/601169

This product is able to send some data about the location/status of the device using GSM cellphone towers, globally. I was wondering how this is possible without paying subscription fees to a carrier/network provider. Although there is a flat annual fee to be charged by Victorinox, is it enough to cover expensive global roaming costs?

Comment: Edited my question to narrow the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about a particular product are usually best answered by the seller / manufacturer of that product. From their website, I have been able to answer & correct some of your points. You said:

> I want to build a similar tracking device for a weather balloon

In that case, this is not the device you want to use. That is because your comment that:

> it will transmit the GPS position no matter where your bag is in the world

... is not true. :-(

The [PDF of the Quick Start Guide](https://www.victorinox.com/mam/celum/celum_assets/8823519019038_CheckSmart_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf?1&attachement=true) says:

> "The CheckSmart Luggage Tracker uses cell towers to locate your luggage, not GPS"

In their [FAQ page for the product](https://www.victorinox.com/global/en/Travel-Gear-FAQ-CheckSmart/cms/service-travel-gear-faq-checksmart), they say:

> "Does CheckSmart work on GPS?
>
> No. GPS generally does not operate within airport terminals and baggage loading areas. The CheckSmart Luggage Tracker device emits a signal that is used to determine its location, but does not use GPS."

So if you want the GPS location of your balloon, this device won't help you.

Finally, you said:

> how is it able to transmit data without needed the customer to pay for a plan

Notice that in the FAQ page linked earlier, it says:

> "Apart from the activation and annual service fees no other charges apply to CheckSmart Luggage Tracker"

This suggests that there effectively *is* a (cellular service) "plan", which is called "annual service fee".

There are many designs for GPS trackers which report location via GSM, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at Quick_Start_Guide of this product: https://www.victorinox.com/mam/celum/celum_assets/8823519019038_CheckSmart_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf?1&attachement=true . This tracker has a pre-installed SIM card. I think customer will pay for a plan once she or he active this card.

I know little about any weather balloon, but I think wireless sensor nodes will be a good choice if you have many balloons, or your balloon is so big that you need several wireless sensor nodes.